# Django - Return none object if record not found given the queried list

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I've a list of ids `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Now I want to query a model with the above list of ids. This is how I perform the operation.

```
ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

This returns objects of ModelA which match the given `id` list. Now consider ids `[2,3,5]` were not present. Can I get a queryset of same length as that of the input list, including all the non-found objects as well.??

For eg:-

if `[2,3,5]` are not found, it should return

```
[1,None,None,4,None,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like...

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
results = ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
result_ids = [result.id for result in results]
return [id if id in result_ids else None for id in ids]
```

Comment: I don't know how the database would respond signifying that there is a blank row. Why does it have to be done in the database?

Comment: Because I dont want things to happen at the application level, involving loops.

Comment: OK. Well I can't imagine that the database can do it on it's own. If anything, the Django ORM would do something very similar to this, which would still be on the application level.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast If you want it done at the db level, you'll probably need to write a raw SQL statement. Nonetheless, you should revise your question to include that you would like it done at the db level as most people will assume you want it done at the application level based on your question tags and given code.